# KeePassX - cross platform

Tags: crossplatform, keepass, keepassx

I have recently installed KeePassX on my Ubuntu desktop, and I noticed that it only requires a master key to login. There is no email or signup required. Because of this, I was questioning its accessibility on other computers. Lets say my current computer with KeePassX installed on it crashes. Is there any way I can download KeePassX onto another computer and be able to open my database with all my information in it?

Comment: I just updated from 14.04 to 16.04 and the KeePassX database has changed. So it updated old database and now is not compatible with the older version in 14.04. It is just a .kbdx encrypted file on your system. I have copied from one system to another without issue (other than finding the right location.)

Comment: So as long as I save my .kbd file, it will work in any version of KeePassX?

Comment: KeePassX new version 2.0 change to .kbdx is now compatible with KeePass 2. https://www.keepassx.org/news/ You may need older copy as .kdb depending on what version you use. And once newer version cannot convert back, but still have older version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keepassx is only a secure vault for password storage in a file.
It's your charge to backup the file on a regular basis.

An option to get access to your file everywhere might be the use of cloud based storage (self hosted or as service). Keep in mind that cloud sotrage shouldn't be considered as the only way to backup things.

Comment: So if I backup my .kbd file, I can use that to access my info in KeyPassX on other computers?

Comment: exactly, even mobile devices (check for file formats, do a little test on all your environment to make sure you can load your kbd).

Comment: @dhaneku.b KeePass is available for [Windows](http://keepass.info/) - KeePassX is in fact a port of that application to Linux.  There seems to be a version for Mac also

Comment: Yeah, I understood that part. I just wanted to make sure I could save my database in KeePass, just in case something happened to my computer. I didn't want to lose all my info.

Comment: @Charles Green, you're right, and since a few time now, keepassx is also [available on windows](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads/), a port of a ported app.

Comment: @Damien - bizarre - ported over, then ported back...

Comment: @Charles, yes and on top of that, keepass (v2) has  linux version using mono ... It's a port-ception :)